# How can I cover persistent ghosting in a rendered wall?

Tags: render

About 12 months ago I rendered a wall at the end of my garden using a lime, cement mix render. It looked great at first, and it is still better than the blocks, but there a ghosting where wet patches show through, sometimes showing the pattern of bricks behind.

I have noticed recently the pattern doesn't go away in dry weather anymore, so I have to cover the render with something else.

Maybe mineral breathable masonry paint? This would be expensive, and would it last?

What I would like to try is a cement+lime wash with SBR admixture painted on with a roller, this should give a light grey finish and the SBR may prevent moisture or patterns from underneath showing through?

[image: Picture of rendered wall with dark patches]

Comment: Paint would be the simplest answer. (Personally, I'd consider treating it as a stage backdrop and taking full advantage of the paint to make it more decorative. Faux "stone wall" effects are easy even if you can't paint a straight line without masking...)

Comment: No idea on the relative cost, but perhaps a more substantial "render", *i.e.* what's called "pebble dash" if I recall correctly from the wrong side of the pond?

Comment: What's on the back of the wall is also a potential issue. Plus I'd want to have some sort of capping on the top, preferably one which throws the water clear of the wall. Any wall constantly getting wet and drying out will leave patterns on the face due to small inconsistences in the material (a mortar joint is thermally different to a block for example so will dry out at a different rate).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for ideas, a few weeks ago I painted the whole wall in two coats of SBR mixed into 5 parts water using a roller, let it dry a day or so and then covered it in masonry paint. A month later it looks spectacular, long may it last. I was sure to coat the top of the wall with SBR and paint as there is no capping.